# Cant stage changes of adding new subfolder using git add

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Using vscode and copied over a new subfolder with some python scripts I need to commit into a branch.

within the terminal, I used git add . in the root. Then git status
The results were

Changes not staged for commit:
...my folder & subfolder were listed here

Why is this subfolder not being staged for commit?  What can I check?